# My Symfony2 Form for Many to Many is empty

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

I have a Many to Many relationship between Hospital and Vendor, but when I try to add the hospitals to my VendorType, the form is rendered with no hospitals as <option>'s

This is the relevant snippets from my code.

VendorBundle/Entity/Vendor.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Incompass\VendorBundle\Entity\Repository\VendorRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Vendor
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Incompass\HospitalBundle\Entity\Hospital", inversedBy="authorized_vendors")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="AuthorizedVendor",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="vendor_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="hospital_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $authorized_hospitals;
```

HospitalBundle/Entity/Hospital.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Incompass\HospitalBundle\Entity\Repository\HospitalRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Hospital
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Incompass\VendorBundle\Entity\Vendor", mappedBy="authorized_hospitals")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="AuthorizedVendor",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="hospital_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="vendor_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $authorized_vendors;
```

VendorBundle/Form/VendorType.php

```
class VendorType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder->add('authorized_hospitals', 'entity',
                    array(
                        'class' => 'IncompassHospitalBundle:Hospital',
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'property' => 'name'
                    )
                )
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('address', 'text')
                ->add('phone', 'text');
    }
```

/AdminBundle/Resources/views/Vendors/new.html.twig

```
<section class="col-md-12">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
</section>
```

And this is what gets rendered, I have some Hospitals in the database so I'm not sure why they are not showing up in the select.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required" for="authorized_hospitals">Authorized hospitals</label>
    <select id="authorized_hospitals" name="authorized_hospitals[]" required="required" class="form-control" multiple="multiple"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked this out now, I had to add a query_builder option to my FormType

```
$builder->add('authorized_hospitals', 'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'IncompassHospitalBundle:Hospital',
                'multiple' => true,
                'property' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('h');
                    return $qb->orderBy('h.name', 'DESC');
                }
            )
        )
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('address', 'text')
        ->add('phone', 'text');
```

}